# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.sakhnin.classes.MonthlySummary

Tags: java, android, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to print all date in this MonthlyReport and got this exception.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet showMettingReports threw
>   exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be
>   cast to com.sakhnin.classes.MonthlySummary    at
>   org.apache.jsp.jspFiles.showMettingReports_jsp._jspService(showMettingReports_jsp.java:150)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>     at com.sakhnin.implementations.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:140)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.sakhnin.classes.MonthlySummary

**MonthlySummary.java**

```
public class MonthlySummary {
    @Id
    private String Date;
    private int Cost;
    private String Place;
    private String Start;
    private String End;
    private String Description;
    private int MentorID;

    public MonthlySummary() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public MonthlySummary(String place, String date, String start, String end,
        String description, int cost, int mentorID) {
    super();
    Place = place;
    Date = date;
    Start = start;
    End = end;
    Description = description;
    Cost = cost;
    MentorID = mentorID;
}
```

**MonthlySummaryIMP.java**

```
 public List<MonthlySummary> getMentorReportsById(int id) {
    List<MonthlySummary> reports=null;
    try{
    session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    // Fetch all active coupons whose businesses' parent's category is as got in the argument
    SQLQuery query =  session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MonthlySummary WHERE MentorID="+id );
    reports = query.list();
    closeSession();
    }
    catch(HibernateException e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return reports;

}
```

**jsp file**

```
<tbody>
  <%
    List<MonthlySummary> m = (List<MonthlySummary>)request.getSession().getAttribute("meetingsReports");

    for(MonthlySummary report : m) {
  %>

  <td>Date<%=report.getDate() %></td>
  <td>Date<%=report.getPlace()%></td>
  <td>Date<%=report.getStart()%></td>
  <td>Date<%=report.getEnd()%></td>
  <td>Date<%=report.getDescription() %></td>
  <td>Date<%=report.getCost()%></td>

  <%
    }
  %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Where did you add this `meetingsReports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid such `ClassCastException`, you need  to add Entity into your query object. 
Try below--

```
SQLQuery query =  session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MonthlySummary WHERE MentorID="+id );

query.addEntity(MonthlySummary.class);

reports = query.list();
--rest of code
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thnaks :)

Answer (score 0):

As your stack trace suggests that the its trying to cast List of `MonthlySummary` but actually it cannot understand the left hand object to complete this process.

This kind of strange because if you would have not set the `HTTPSession` attribute on the first hand it should give you Null Pointer Exception.

Are you sure that you are not setting any attribute with that key, my assumption here is that you are setting some other object in that key.

Please use the trick mentioned by [Sighr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4029920/singhr) and that should do the magic for you.